# UICollectionView accessing indexPath Cell of another CollectionView

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, swift3

I have this Main Page which is PhotoStreamViewController that has a CollectionView, what I want to happen is when I click one picture of the collectionView from the PhotoStreamController, it will automatically go to the DetailStreamController's page collectionView then I can swipe left and right the same photos from the PhotoStreamViewController, my problem is the segue from PhotoStreamViewController to, DetailStreamController.
    import UIKit

```
class Photo {

    class func allPhotos() -> [Photo] {
        var photos = [Photo]()
        if let URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Photos 2", withExtension: "plist") {
            print(URL)
            if let photosFromPlist = NSArray(contentsOf: URL) {
                print(photosFromPlist)

                for dictionary in photosFromPlist {
                    let photo = Photo(dictionary: dictionary as! NSDictionary)
                    photos.append(photo)
                }
            }
        }
        return photos
    }

    var image: UIImage
    init(image: UIImage) {
        self.image = image
    }

    convenience init(dictionary: NSDictionary) {
        let photo = dictionary["imageName"] as? String
        let image = UIImage(named: photo!)?.decompressedImage
        self.init(image: image!)
    }
}
```

here's my code of PhotoStreamController

```
import UIKit
    class PhotoStreamViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

        var parentController: UIViewController?   

        @IBOutlet var photoStream: UICollectionView!

        var photos = Photo.allPhotos()


        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
         if let cell = sender as? UICollectionViewCell {

            if let indexPath = self.photoStream?.indexPath(for: cell) {
            if segue.identifier == "StreamToStreamDeatilController" {
                let photoViewController : StreamDetailController = segue.destination     as! StreamDetailController
                photoViewController. " I dont know what to put here" this is the missing code. cause I cant access the Class Photo
                }
             } 
           }
         }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return photos.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cellA = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Celler", for: indexPath) as! AnnotatedPhotoCell
        cellA.box = Box(fImage: photos[indexPath.row].image)
        return cellA
    }
}

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let paper = photoDataSource.photoForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
           performSegue(withIdentifier: "StreamToStreamDeatilController", sender: paper)
        }
    }
}
```

[ExtraViewCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdhNB.png)

[StreamDetailController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvQFS.png)

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear about the problem you are facing?

Comment: Can you please check your second class and verify the code ? it's got lots of extra curled braces, etc.. after you make sure what you posted here is exactly the same code as you have we can take a look and help further

Comment: Also, can you please post an example of what you mean by `cause I cant access the Class Photo` ? what errors are thrown ?

Comment: Edited it, added some photos of other codes! @Rikh Thank you in a advance

Comment: anyway I solved it already, now my only problem is, It's not scrolling